# Get pathname to file from Maven resources

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd

I currently have a method that validates an XML file by comparing it to an XSD file.

```
private boolean validateXmlFile() {
    try {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Schema schema;

        schema = factory.newSchema(new File("school.xsd"));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        Source source = new StreamSource(new File("school.xml"));

        validator.validate(source);

        return true;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Initially, the XSD file was located in the main directory, but now I am currently trying to convert my project so that it is 'mavenised', which involves putting all of my files in a 'resources/' directory.

How do I call the pathname to the XSD file now that it is in the resources directory? Obviously I can't do it this way:

```
schema = factory.newSchema(new File("resources/school.xsd"));
```

Does it involve referring to the file as an InputStream?

Many thanks

Comment: `this.class.getResourcesAsStream("/school.xsd");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for, thanks anyways:

```
schema = factory.newSchema(new File(this.getClass().getResource("school.xsd").toURI()));
```